# Squashing Prisma migrations

Tags: postgresql, orm, prisma

I am trying to squash multiple migrations created by Prisma into one before going to production. Here are the instructions:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/workflows/squashing-migrations

I started with:

schema.prisma

```
model Project {
  id     Int      
  name   String
}
```

Added 'city' property:

```
model Project {
  id     Int      
  name   String
  city   String //new
}
```

Run `npx prisma migrate dev`

Added 'rate' property:

```
model Project {
  id     Int      
  name   String
  city   String 
  rate   Int //new
}
```

Run `npx prisma migrate dev`

Removed 'rate' property:

```
model Project {
  id     Int      
  name   String
  city   String
}
```

Run `npx prisma migrate dev`.

I ended up with 3 migration files under `prisma/migrations`. I deleted them all as instructed in article and run `npx prisma migrate dev` to create one migration file that corresponds to changes in `schema.prisma`.
Response:

```
Drift detected: Your database schema is not in sync with your migration history.

The following is a summary of the differences between the expected database schema given your migrations files, and the actual schema of the database.

It should be understood as the set of changes to get from the expected schema to the actual schema.

[*] Changed the `Project` table
  [+] Added column `city`

? We need to reset the "public" schema at "localhost:5432"
Do you want to continue? All data will be lost.
```

Also tried the same with manually removing entries for those migrations from _prisma_migrations table. Still the same result.

Can squashing be done without data loss? What am I doing wrong?